# How to get an Apple refresh token from Cognito?

Tags: swift, amazon-cognito, sign-in-with-apple

I'm using Cognito's federated sign in with Sign In With Apple. I have an API Gateway route using a JWT Authorizer through appleid.apple.com From the iOS app, if I pass the identity token to this API Gateway route and it appears to work.

After 10 mins, the Apple identity token expires as expected. Do I have to manually [verify a user and fetch a refresh token](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/sign_in_with_apple_rest_api/verifying_a_user) or does Cognito offer an endpoint to do this for me and return a refresh token?

[image]

There is not an ALLOW_REFRESH_TOKEN_AUTH option available.

Comment: Documentation for adding Sign in with Apple as an authentication provider to an identity pool [https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/apple.html]

Comment: The link doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS Support said "If you are using Authorization Code grant then refresh token will be generated once the flow is completed. The Authorization code grant flow initiates a code grant flow, which provides an authorization code as the response. This code can be exchanged for access tokens with the TOKEN Endpoint. Because the tokens are never exposed directly to an end user, they are less likely to become compromised." and referenced me here:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/understanding-amazon-cognito-user-pool-oauth-2-0-grants/

Answer (score 1):

Cognito offers a refresh token endpoint. When you set up the app client for your userpool in Auth Flows Configuration,  the option "ALLOW_REFRESH_TOKEN_AUTH" is already selected by default, then click "save app client changes"[image: You create the app client for your user pool]

Comment: Thanks. It's on by default and I can't toggle it on or off just like in your screenshot.

Comment: Exactly, so it is by default that you get a refresh token by Cognito. What you can alter is the validation period from the Refresh token expiration fields

Comment: "it is by default that you get a refresh token by Cognito" - If I'm using a JWT Authorizer with the API Gateway, at which point in the process do I get this refresh token? The JWT Authorizer passes these keys to the Gateway Route aud, auth_time, c_hash, exp, iat, iss, nonce_supported, sub. I'm not seeing a refresh token in there.

Comment: `let data = {
    grant_type: 'authorization_code',
    code: code,
    redirect_uri: YOUR_REDIRECT_URI,
    scope: 'email openid profile',
    client_id: YOUR_APP_CLIENT_ID
  }
  const response = await axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: your_authorization_url_token,
    auth: {
      username: YOUR_APP_CLIENT_ID,
      password: YOUR_APP_CLIENT_SECRET
    },
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    data: qs.stringify(data)
  }) `
the `response.data` of this ^ should contain the id_token and the rerfesh_token

Comment: I haven't used JWT Authorizer, this how I did the call to get the tokens in node.js. I think it won't be very different for you or at least maybe I help you with a hint. I hope it helps!